# Problems With Beginner python project (number guesser) repetition issue

Tags: python

I have started a python beginner project where the computer guesses the user's number by entering whether it's higher or lower than `x`. However, I have managed the first part but my program stops and does not carry on. My guess is that I need to include a loop somewhere to repeat the `nextguess()` within the code but I cannot figure out where.

This is my code:

```
maxnum = 1000
min = 1
guess = 500

print("1 = Higher 2 = Lower 3 = Correct")
print("Pick a number dont tell me what it is!")
print("The highest number you can pick is:",maxnum)
print("The lowest number you can pick is:",min)
print("Is it higher or lower than:",guess)
maxnum = maxnum +1;
choice = input()
choiceprop = int(choice)

def nextguess():
    guess = (maxnum + min) / 2
    print("Is it lower or higher than:", guess)
  
if choiceprop == 1:
    min = guess
    nextguess()
    maxnum = maxnum +1;

if choiceprop == 2:
    maxnum = guess
    nextguess()
    maxnum = maxnum +1;

if choiceprop == 3:
    print("nice!");
```

Comment: check [while](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) statement and nest your guessing logic in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what part of the code needs to be repeated: it’s the part that asks for a next input, and generates a next guess.

That’s pretty much all of your code, except for the preamble, and the definition of `nextguess`:

```
def nextguess():
    guess = (maxnum + min) / 2
    print("Is it lower or higher than:", guess)


maxnum = 1000
min = 1
guess = 500

print("1 = Higher 2 = Lower 3 = Correct")
print("Pick a number dont tell me what it is!")
print("The highest number you can pick is:", maxnum)
print("The lowest number you can pick is:", min)
print("Is it higher or lower than:", guess)

while True:
    choice = input()
    choiceprop = int(choice)
    
    if choiceprop == 1:
        min = guess
    elif choiceprop == 2:
        maxnum = guess
    elif choiceprop == 3:
        print("nice!")
        break
    
    nextguess()
    maxnum = maxnum + 1
```

However, this code still won’t work, because your logic for generating guesses is incorrect: why are you increasing `maxnum`? Surely the maximum can’t change. Next, your `nextguess` generates non-integral guesses. You need to restrict this to integer numbers.

Finally, `nextguess` also won’t change your global variable `guess`, you need to *return* your next guess, and assign it:

```
def nextguess(min, max):
    guess = (min + max) // 2
    print("Is it lower or higher than:", guess)
    return guess
```

… and now, when calling `nextguess` you need to pass it a minumum and maximum bound.

With this change, you also don’t need to hard-code your initial guess: just call `nextguess` at the beginning.

```
def nextguess(min, max):
    guess = (min + max) // 2
    print("Is it lower or higher than:", guess)
    return guess


max = 1000
min = 1

print("1 = Higher 2 = Lower 3 = Correct")
print("Pick a number dont tell me what it is!")
print("The highest number you can pick is:", max)
print("The lowest number you can pick is:", min)

while True:
    guess = nextguess(min, max)
    choice = int(input())
    
    if choice == 1:
        min = guess
    elif choice == 2:
        max = guess
    elif choice == 3:
        print("nice!")
        break
    
    guess = nextguess(min, max)
```

(PS: Don’t use `;` in Python.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to use binary search to zero down on the user's number, you'll need to keep an eye on how numbers are rounded and how you shift your boundaries in response to the user's input.

As far as keeping it going beyond the first input, you'll need to put the portions that take the user's input and makes the next guess in a while loop, making sure you have a code stop condition or logic within the loop body to prevent it from looping infinitely.

Here's an example of how it could be done:

```
import math

def main():
  min = 0
  max = 1000

  print("Pick a number dont tell me what it is!")
  print("The highest number you can pick is:", max)
  print("The lowest number you can pick is:", min)

  while max >= min:
    guess = math.ceil((max + min) / 2)

    print("Is it higher or lower than: ", guess)
    print('1. Higher')
    print('2. Lower')
    print('3. Correct')

    choiceprop = int(input('Option: '))

    if choiceprop == 1:
      min = guess + 1 # guess can be excluded safely
    elif choiceprop == 2:
      max = guess - 1
    else:
      print('nice')
      break

main()
```